# Load one-line-json formatted data into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a json doc with 7 columns and only 1 row.I am not able to load this Json into a DataFrame with read_json.

```
url_global = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/'

df_global = pd.read_json(url_global)


ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Comment: Can you post your JSON?

Comment: Please add your example Code and JSON File.

Comment: edited the post

Answer (score 0):

The params in this function is somehow complicated and un-orthogonal. I find it helpful to use

```
pds.read_json("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/", typ='series')
```

output would be (the type is 'pandas.core.series.Series')

```
active_assets                       6.770000e+02
active_currencies                   9.170000e+02
active_markets                      9.790000e+03
bitcoin_percentage_of_market_cap    4.565000e+01
last_updated                        1.522332e+09
total_24h_volume_usd                1.386394e+10
total_market_cap_usd                2.790481e+11
dtype: float64
```

The reason is that your json is not really a `DataFrame` (matrix) and is more like a `Series` (row). To find more about its functionality (concerning what are valid DF and how axes are arranged), refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html.

Comment: By the way I never knew `pds` reads url so conveniently before this post.